# Load url selected object in UIWebView (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uiwebview, indexing

I want to open a UIWebView with a url based on the index of a custom object from an array. When I tap a button, based upon the index of objects in an array, I need for the UIWebView to open up that particular url. The problem is that when I open the webview, it will only load the url of the first object (at index 0) in the array. Here is my code:

**.m:**

//Here's a snippet of my viewDidLoad method.

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

buyButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
            buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(228, 8, 25, 25);
            [buyButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buy-now.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyBttnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview:buyButton];

                 int count = [self->myArray count];
                 for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
               {
                     DomainModel *eachObject = [self->myArray objectAtIndex:buyButton.tag];
                     buyButton.tag = index;  

                     urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",eachObject.url];
                     NSLog(@"Selected index:  %d",urlString);

                }


    -(void)buyBttnPressed:(id)sender{


        UIWebView *buyView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9,132,305,368)];
        buyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        buyView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        buyView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:buyView];

        UIButton *cancelBttn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        cancelBttn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        cancelBttn.frame = CGRectMake(3, 5, 25, 25);
        [cancelBttn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buyView addSubview:cancelBttn];


     [buyView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];

    }
```

How do I fix the loop so that when the buyBttn is pressed, the the url associated with the associated index loads?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that if you call this code on buyBtnPressed, then the TAG of the button will be set to the self.myArray.count -1 always (you're looping but setting it always on the same button).
so current will always point to the same item - the last one in the list.
i think this:

```
int i = 0;
for (MyObject *obj in self->myArray)
{

    i++;
    btn.tag = i;      

 }
```

should be done on viewDidLoad, or wherever you fill your array in.

Comment: So then where should I declare the UIButton for the tag?.. @shaish

Comment: where are you adding the buybutton to the view?

in your code you're setting the tag of the same buyButton again and again..